# Firebase Authentication Error (auth/invalid-email)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement a firebase sign in/log in form in a ReactJS app. Registration is working properly (as far as I can tell) and thus adding data to the authentication and firestore database isn't an issue. The specific problem I'm having is that upon attempting to log in with a proper email and password, it throws an error (auth/invalid-email). Any help in figuring out exactly where I'm going wrong is appreciated as this is my first time developing anything like this.

Code I have currently:

```jsx
import React, { useState } from 'react';
// import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'; // Commented out for future routing
import FormWrapper from "../../components/FormWrapper";
import TextInput from "../../components/TextInput";
import SecondaryButton from "../../components/SecondaryButton";
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth"; // Import your Firebase configuration

function SignInForm() {
    const auth = getAuth();
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    // const history = useHistory(); // Commented out for future routing

    const handleSignIn = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        
        try {
            await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);

            // Uncomment the following lines for routing
            // history.push('/dashboard');

            const timestamp = new Date().toLocaleString();
            alert(`User has been logged in at ${timestamp}.`);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Sign-in error:', error.message);
            alert(`Sign-in error: ${error.message}`);
        }
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSignIn}>
            <FormWrapper title="Log In">
                <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
                    <TextInput
                        required
                        type="email"
                        label="Email"
                        value={email}
                        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        required
                        type="password"
                        label="Password"
                        value={password}
                        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                    />

                    <SecondaryButton text="Log In" type="submit" />
                </div>
            </FormWrapper>
        </form>
    );
}

export default SignInForm;
```

I also checked the networking section of the devtools, and this is what the network request looks like:

```json
{
    "clientType": "CLIENT_TYPE_WEB",
    "email": "",
    "password": "",
    "returnSecureToken": true
}
```

The following is what the text input component looks like

```jsx
const TextInput = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-1">
      <label className="font-light text-gray-600 text-sm">{props.label}</label>
      <input
        type={props.type}
        className="border-gray-200 border rounded w-full p-2 focus:outline-0"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextInput;
```

Comment: What does your `TextInput` component look like? Exactly what value does it pass to its `onChange` prop?

Comment: @RenaudTarmac: while the root cause may be the same, the code here seems quite different. Can you comment to clarify what you think the problem is, and how OP should address it?

Answer (score 0):

Your `TextInput` component doesn't make use of any `onChange` prop. In short, you're never handling value changes so your `email` and `password` state properties are always empty strings.

Forward the appropriate props onto the `<input>` element within your component

```jsx
const TextInput = ({ label, ...inputProps }) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-1">
      <label className="font-light text-gray-600 text-sm">{label}</label>
      <input
        {...inputProps}
        className="border-gray-200 border rounded w-full p-2 focus:outline-0"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextInput;
```

This will ensure the `value` and `onChange` are used correctly.